# wrong array length in java

Tags: java, arrays

I've defined an array initialized with 12 elements, but the value of its *length* attribute is set to 10 by JVM and I cannot access the 11th and 12th elements. What should I do to solve the problem?
Assume that this array is defined as follows:

```
private static final Type[] p = new Type[]{ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null };
```

and in some function I use Type x = p[11]; then I get the above exception

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please show your code and be clear what do you want to ask.

Comment: what have you done.....please show the code........

Comment: You probably counted wrong.

Comment: Personally I feel, instead of 4-5 person saying same comment "Show us your code" you could have upvoted the one "Show us your code comment" :)

Comment: that way, @Adrian Blackburn needn't have posted a **Comment** as an **Answer**.

Comment: I guarantee that the JVM has done no such thing.

Comment: I just tried with you code, I am able to get length as 12, and able to access p[11] element successfully. Share more code where you are accessing it, method etc

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    System.out.println(arr[11]);
}
```

This will print 12. Array index starts from 0 to arr.lenghth-1. So if you want to access arr[12] you will get  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
public class SetTest {
private static final String[] arr1 = { null, null, null, null, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, null, null };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String p = arr1[11];
    System.out.println(p);
    System.out.println(arr1.length);

}
}
```

Output:

```
null
12
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer for above question

Comment: @PradeepSimha I think OP want to access 12th element inside array using arr[12]. So I write above answer.

Comment: _but the value of its length attribute is set to 10_ so still we are not clear about question.

Comment: assume I have some field defined as :private static final Type[] p = new Type[]{ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null }; and in some function I use Type x = p[11]; then I get the above exception

Comment: @user1723583 I tried with String and it works fine. See my code above and output.

Comment: I found the problem. I had made a mistake somewhere in code. Sorry for this silly question